# Galeria Masonry con infinite scroll en Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes es la primera vez que utilizo estas librerias para ordenar las fotos con posición absoluta y dependiendo el espacio y además el infinite scroll pero con botón de ver más, pero no consigo hacerla funcionar correctamente:

En mi controlador:

```
$fotos = Gallery::paginate(6);
```

En mi vista:

```
<section class="galeria">
    <div class="col-12 espacioModulo">
        <div class="grid" id="mygrid">
            @foreach ($fotos as $item)
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <img src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}" alt="" class="">
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        {{ $fotos->links() }}
        <p>
            <button class="view-more-button">View more</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Y el script que de momento me hace funcionar bien la galeria pero no el ver más:

```
<script>
    //$('ul.pagination').hide();
    $('.grid').infiniteScroll({
        // options
        path: 'ul.pagination li:last-child a',
        checkLastPage: 'ul.pagination li:last-child a',
        button: '.view-more-button',
        scrollThreshold: false,
        append: '.grid-item',
    });

    $('.grid').masonry({
        // options...
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        //columnWidth: 200,
        horizontalOrder: true
      });
</script>
```

Estoy utilizando esta libreria [aquí](https://infinite-scroll.com/options.html#checklastpage)

Al ser Laravel estoy utilizando `ul.pagination li:last-child a` para el cambio de página, según la documentación en `checkLastPage: 'ul.pagination li:last-child a',` se pone la paginación y en   `path` se hace algo así: `path: 'news/blog-p{{#}}.html',` pero aquí ya no se que hacer.

**Edición**
SI funciona, cuando le doy al botón de `view-more-button` me carga el page=2 en la url, pero las imagenes que carga al darle al botón, si las carga con `grid-item` pero no lo detecta `masonry` y me pone una abajo de la otra. Es decir parece que lo que cargo con el botón no hereda lo que crea masonry.

Comment: En la misma documentación hay [una opción para combinar con Masonry](https://infinite-scroll.com/options.html#outlayer) e incluye enlace a un [codepen de ejemplo](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/NWRYWgd) con todo el código necesario.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, no lo supe interpretar bien, pero ahora ya lo tengo funcionando! gracias.