# Masonry + infiniteScroll + Isotope en Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Buenos días tengo una galeria cargada de un BD y utilizo la libreria Masonry y además el infinite scroll con un botón de show more para ir cargando más contenido. Esto está funcionando perfectamente, pero arriba de la galería tengo unos botones que ejercen de filtrador para las imagenes, para ello estoy utilizando [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) que es del mismo creador que masonry he infinite scroll.

El problema es que como hay contenido que esta en la primera página o segunda, si el contenido de una de las pestañas esta en la segunda página no se reproduce, paso a detallaros el código.

En mi controlador traigo la galeria de la BD con un paginate:

```
public function gallery()
    {
        $fotos = Gallery::paginate(8);
        //dd($fotos);
        return view('gallery')->with(['fotos' => $fotos]);
    }
```

Luego en mi vista este es el menú que quiero utilizar para filtrar el contenido:

```
<div class="menuZonas">
  <div class="lasZonas">
      <ul id="filters">
         <a class="filter" data-filter=".ferrari"><li class="bordeZonas activaZona">Ferrari</li></a>
         <a class="filter" data-filter=".lotus"><li class="bordeZonas">Lotus</li></a>
         <a class="filter" data-filter=".mclaren"><li class="bordeZonas">McLaren</li></a>
         <a class="filter" data-filter=".training"><li class="bordeZonas">Training</li></a>
         <a class="filter" data-filter=".scenes"><li>Behind the scenes</li></a>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Luego itero la fotos:

```
<section class="galeria">
    <div class="col-12 espacioModulo">
        <div class="grid" id="mygrid">
            @foreach ($fotos as $item)
                <div class="grid-item {{ $item->filter }}" data-category="{{ $item->filter }}">
                    <img src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}" alt="" class="">
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        {{ $fotos->links() }}
        <div class="page-load-status">
            <div class="loader-ellips infinite-scroll-request">
              <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
              <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
              <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
              <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
            </div>
            <p class="infinite-scroll-last">No hay más contenido que mostrar</p>
            <p class="infinite-scroll-error">No hay más páginas para cargar</p>
        </div>
        <div class="center topShowMore">
            <button class="view-more-button btnShow">Show more</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Código JavaScrit:

```
<script>
    $('ul.pagination').hide();

    let $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
        // Masonry options...
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    });

    // get Masonry instance
    let msnry = $grid.data('masonry');

    $grid.infiniteScroll({
        // Infinite Scroll options...
        path: 'ul.pagination li:last-child a',
        checkLastPage: 'ul.pagination li:last-child a',
        button: '.view-more-button',
        scrollThreshold: false,
        append: '.grid-item',
        status: '.page-load-status',
        outlayer: msnry,
    });
</script>
```

Luego para utilizar el Isotope:

```
  // init Isotope
  $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  });

  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });
```

Pero como os digo no van bien los filtros por que si los resultados están en la página 1 y una pestaña de los que cargo está en la pag 2 no se reproducen. Alguna sugerencia?

He visto [esto](https://codepen.io/Goji/embed/Kpgegd/?theme-id=modal) googleando que parece ser lo que estoy buscando, pero este el inifinite scroll no se hace con un botón, además de que carga las imagenes en una variable, se me hace dificil comprender.

Comment: ¿Usas la misma plantilla para carga inicial y para peticiones AJAX?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Galeria Masonry con infinite scroll en Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/452699/galeria-masonry-con-infinite-scroll-en-laravel)

Comment: No es lo mismo @ManuelRobles aquí estamos añadiendo lo de filtrar, me falta publicar la respuesta ahí, y al ser diferente la pregunta por eso he realizado otra

Comment: Hola @Triby no hago nada con AJAX, todo se realiza con el código que te muestro, si es cierto que pense en cargarlo todo con AJAX, pero ahí se me complica el tema de la paginación que no se como se hace con AJAX, crees que eso puede ser una buena solución?

Comment: @Miguel, probablemente tú no lo haces de forma manual, pero creo que `infiniteScroll` hace esa petición AJAX por ti. Entonces, deberías poder identificar si la petición es normal o con AJAX para devolver el contenido de la plantilla o solo el ciclo.

Comment: mmm ahí me pillas, voy a investigar como lo hace `infiniteScroll`